# Зачем нужен MAC-адрес?

Tags: сеть, mac-address

Помогите разобраться с глупым вопросом "для чего нужен мас-адрес"? Есть ip, есть mac... Первый назначается, второй вшитый... Первого(ip) вроде как с лихвой хватит для работы в сети... Что не так? Зачем мас придумали?

Comment: А что, википедии недостаточно?

Comment: IP-адрес - это место твоего пребывания. Ты можешь быть дома тупить в телек, а можешь уехать к бабушке в деревню пасти коров. MAC-адрес - это твой паспорт. Если тебе пришла посылка на почту, то для доставки достаточно адреса, но для получения её на почте тебе придётся предъявить паспорт.

Answer (score 3):

IP вещь динамичная.
MAC, практически, постоянный.

> В широковещательных сетях (таких, как
> сети на основе Ethernet) MAC-адрес
> позволяет уникально идентифицировать
> каждый узел сети и доставлять данные
> только этому узлу. Таким образом,
> MAC-адреса формируют основу сетей на
> канальном уровне, которую используют
> протоколы более высокого (сетевого)
> уровня. Для преобразования MAC-адресов
> в адреса сетевого уровня и обратно
> применяются специальные протоколы
> (например, ARP и RARP в сетях IPv4 и
> NDP в сетях на основе IPv6).

Например, у меня подключен интернет по MAC адресу. Т.е. только на моем компьютере (роутере) может быть данное подключение. Если бы подключали по IP, то на следующий день у меня бы не было сети.

Comment: Не стоило сводить описанное в цитате к тому, что МАС постоянный для того, чтобы быть постоянным или для того, чтобы ограничить вам интернет. Он, в первую очередь, используется для доставки пакетов внутри сети.

Comment: "практически" -- слово правильное. Многие nic (network interface controller) позволяют программно менять MAC.

Comment: xEdelweiss, я привел простой пример. Если автор вопроса не может понять, что написано в Вики, то такие трудные примеры как у вас он вряд ли поймет.
Изначально было просто про мой доступ в интернет.
Потом я скопировал цитату из Вики. Но да, получилось, что это как бы вывод из цитаты. Согласен, не очень.

Comment: Спасибо за ответы... А если получится так, что в локальной сети будут несколько компов с одинаковыми мас адресами, то что произойдет?

Comment: те у которых одинаковый мак будут постоянно терять пакеты, вплоть до нерабочего состояния сети на них

Comment: Ну, терять не будут. Все успешно прочтут один и тот же пакет. 

Но протоколы обмена типа TCP могут сбиться (устойчиво работать не будет).

Comment: ну я это и имел ввиду, под терять.